# ID exist in the table but it is not fetching in select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
profileID   varchar(100)    
height      varchar(100)    
age         varchar(100)
```

My profileID is AA05000011

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `profileID` ='AA05000011'
```

it gives me

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0006 seconds.)

but when I browse I can see an entry with the same ID

Comment: SQL won't get this wrong - check for trailing spaces and non printing characters.

Comment: *when I browse I can see an entry with the same ID* Look for another columns values in this row. Select this row using another columns, and additionally select `HEX(profileID)`. Look for all bytes codes, compare with `SELECT HEX('AA05000011')` output.

Comment: @P.Salmon that is fine but how to avoid these trailing spaces and non-printing characters

Comment: *how to avoid these trailing spaces and non-printing characters* You may correct them (trim in a trigger). You may simply eject incorrect values by CHECK constraint.